# Form as instance variable

Tags: delphi, properties, dispatch

In need that a form knows another, to dispatch behavior. In the past, i need this, and solves using properties. Now, i do the same procedure, but didnt works.

I have the next UML diagram class, sorry, the name class are confuse:
[image]

So, i need thaht ENPViewGeneric knows ENPView. And the children inherit that knowledge.

Im try in **ENPViewGeneric**:

```
unit EnpViewGeneric;
[...]
protected
   { Protected declarations }
   FENPForm: TENP;
public
    { Public declarations }
    property ENPForm: TENP read FENPForm write FENPForm;
[...]
```

The **ENPViewAddAfter** instanciation is performed within an ENPView instance:

```
procedure TENP.optAddLastOfClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AfterForm: TEnpAddAfter;
begin
  AfterForm := TEnpAddAfter.Create(self);
  AfterForm.ENPForm := self;
  AfterForm.ShowModal();
end;
```

Now, the **ENPViewAddAfter** instance, needs querying the **ENPView** instance. So, i defined a public method in **ENPView** to do the query. The method is:

```
function getSelectedRowValues(): TStringList;
```

So, this code, fails with Access Violation in fisrt line:

```
procedure TEnpAddAfter.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  row: TStringList;
  nroMuestraNvo: integer;
begin
  row := ENPForm.getSelectedRowValues();
  nroMuestraNvo := StrToInt(row[0]) + 1;
  muestra.Text := IntToStr(nroMuestraNvo);
end;
```

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Well, you're assigning to the property (ENPForm) after the form has been created, but trying to use it in that form's OnCreate method - before the property has been assigned.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz   little detail xD. I cut and paste the code within OnShow handler, and works. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Alternatively you might typecast the *owner* to a 'TEnpAddAfter', or you might introduce an *constructor* passing the instance as a parameter and assigning the property before calling the inherited.